# How to find clusters of rows with similar values of a given numerical column?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Test data:

```
sqlite3 tmp.sqlite "create table t (id integer, val integer)"
sqlite3 tmp.sqlite <<EOF
insert into t values
  (0, 0),
  (1, 5),
  (2, 10),
  (3, 14),
  (4, 15),
  (5, 16),
  (6, 20),
  (7, 25),
  (8, 29),
  (9, 30),
  (10, 30),
  (11, 31),
  (12, 35),
  (13, 40)
EOF
```

I will provide two hyper parameters:

- `diff`: how far `val` can be between two rows so that they are considered neighbours.
- `min_neighbours`: how many neighboring rows are needed to consider a group a cluster.

E.g. given:

- `diff`: 1
- `min_neighbours`: 2

I want output:

| id | val | n_neighbours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 14 | 2 |
| 4 | 15 | 3 |
| 5 | 16 | 2 |
| 8 | 29 | 3 |
| 9 | 30 | 4 |
| 10 | 30 | 4 |
| 11 | 31 | 3 |

This is because how many neighbours each row has:

| id | n_neighbours | … |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 | 1 |
| 3 | 14 | 2 |
| 4 | 15 | 3 |
| 5 | 16 | 2 |
| 6 | 20 | 1 |
| 7 | 25 | 1 |
| 8 | 29 | 3 |
| 9 | 30 | 4 |
| 10 | 30 | 4 |
| 11 | 31 | 3 |
| 12 | 35 | 1 |
| 13 | 40 | 1 |

For example:

- row 0: neighbours have value between -1 and 1, so there are no neighbours except itself.
- row 3: neighbours have value between 13 and 15. Therefore there is one neighbour except itself: row 4 which has val 15.
- row 4: neighbours have value between 14 and 16. Therefore two neighbours except itself: row 3 and row 5.

Similar questions are either not about integer ranges or fail to precisely define what similar is supposed to mean:

- [SQl server - Finding rows with similar columns in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381496/sql-server-finding-rows-with-similar-columns-in-a-table)
- [SQL Get Rows With A Similar Column Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597713/sql-get-rows-with-a-similar-column-value)
- [Find rows with duplicate/similar column values MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936371/find-rows-with-duplicate-similar-column-values-mysql)
- [SQL - Finding rows with similar values for a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344228/sql-finding-rows-with-similar-values-for-a-column)

Answer (score 0):

**`RANGE` window function**

This is a perfect application for the `RANGE` window function, which SQLite supports https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT id, val, COUNT(*) OVER (
    ORDER BY val RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING
  ) as c FROM t
) WHERE c > 1
```

produces the desired result:

```
3|14|2
4|15|3
5|16|2
8|29|3
9|30|4
10|30|4
11|31|3
```

To understand this let's run just the inner query:

```
SELECT id, val, COUNT(*) OVER (
  ORDER BY val RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING
) as c FROM t
```

which produces the counts:

```
0|0|1
1|5|1
2|10|1
3|14|2
4|15|3
5|16|2
6|20|1
7|25|1
8|29|3
9|30|4
10|30|4
11|31|3
12|35|1
13|40|1
```

What `RANGE` does is exactly what we want: it looks for an unspecified number of rows before and after the current one, and checks if their value is in our desired range.